# Where are the Proxy Settings in FreeNAS?

Tags: proxy, freenas

I'm behind a proxy and I'm trying to install packages in FreeNAS.  Where can I find the proxy settings?  The export command (along with many other things) isn't installed as part of the standard release.  I imagine there is a config file somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands will do it:

```
setenv HTTP_PROXY http://proxy.domain:port
setenv FTP_PROXY ftp://proxy.domain:port
```

Add these lines to your `.cshrc` or `.profile` in your `~/` directory to keep the changes after reboot.

Also: Apparently if you want to install additional software on FreeNAS you need to use a jail to do so.  Make sure you create the correct type of jail (pluginjail?) to make sure the correct packages are there.  See: http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Installing_non-PBI_Software

Also just in case you were wondering how to do any of the following:

To add a DNS server add the following line in `resolv.conf` in `/etc`.  (You can add more than one).

```
nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Hostname is set in rc.conf in /etc:

```
hostname="FreeNASJail"
```

Default Gateway is set in rc.conf in /etc"

```
defaultrouter="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

See here for more info on rc.conf: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.conf&sektion=5